# iOS Switching from paid to free app, how does one know who previously purchased the app?

Tags: ios

I have a paid app that was released on iOS 4. It hasn't been updated and I'm now reworking it to work with iOS 10. Since in app purchasing was not a thing, I made a free (lite) and paid version of the app. I would like to update the paid version to iOS 10 and change it from paid to free with ads and an in app purchase to remove ads.

I tried researching various methods and I have not found a fool proof way or evidence that one will work in all cases. The two most prevelant methods I found:

1. Use an existing UserDefaults key value to determine if they opened the old app and then grant them no ads in the new version.

I don't think this method will work, as if the app was uninstalled or the user redownloads it after the update they would not have that value.

2. I believe iOS 7 offered receipt checking. Use receipt checking to determine if the user has paid for the app and check if the date is before the new version date.

I'm not sure if this would work either. I saw in the documentation to verify locally. Would everything I need exist if the app was an iOS 4 app originally? Would this work for users who had the app through a promo code? What if they don't have an internet connection at the time they open the app? I had trouble finding sample code for this option to test.

How would I go about doing this? Are any of the methods above the only way or are there others?

Answer (score 0):

Out of all the resources I found on this subject, checking the receipt seems to be your only feasible choice. If you have an account where you purchased your app, you can run the new version of the app via Xcode with that account and see if the receipt validation gives you the expected information. Though installing the app via Xcode may alter the receipt that the account has, you may want to check on that.

`NSUserDefaults` option could work if you were setting any value to `NSUserDefaults` on the iOS 4 version.